# How to remove the padding between mat-grid-tile

Tags: angular, angular-material

Material calculate the width of the tile:

```
width: calc(((25% - 0.75px) * 3) + 2px);
```

it is possible to remove the "0.75px" padding?

Comment: Is the width inline on the element?

Comment: I think these styles are in a host context and can not be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use `gutterSize` as described in the official docs
>   [here](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/api#MatGridList).

See stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-u6f9as?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

If you look at the generated HTML for the second `mat-grid-list`, the width is `width: calc(((25% - 0px) * 2) + 0px);` compared to the width of the first `mat-grid-list` where it is `width: calc(((25% - 0.75px) * 2) + 1px);`.